# Angular 12 Object is possibly 'null' in document.getElementById(elementId)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

In Angular 12 I keep getting this issue:

I want to have an show an element by id ...so I have this:

```
document.getElementById(elementId).style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

I keep getting:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
```

I don't know what it's talking about :(

How can I stop this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the returned value from `getElementById` isn't null:

```
const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
if (element) {
  element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

The return type of `getElementById` is `HTMLElement | null`, as it's very possible the function couldn't find the element.

*You* might know for sure the element exists, but your code doesn't.